# grep -r "pattern" not responding

Tags: command-line, grep

grep version is 2.10.

The command is:

`grep -r "myVariable"`

Grep does not respond, even when i execute it in a folder with a small set of small files. When I run the same thing on another Ubuntu machine, it works fine where (grep version is 2.16)...

I expect `grep` to return nothing or return something like this:

```
path/to/file.c:     myVariable++;
path/to/file2.c:    int myVariable;
```

But command shell halts, and I have to cancel everything using `ctrl+C`:

What is the problem or how do I investigate it?

Comment: Without specifying, what's the command how can you expect someone to help you?

Comment: the command is in the title, Ok I'll edit

Comment: And of course pattern occurs there.

Comment: You should specify which file(s) to search for the pattern. You can use wild cards or a single file, for example `grep "alias" ~/.bashrc` should produce a few lines of output (there are some aliases in the default .bashrc).

Comment: This means that the 2.10 version of grep does not support this feature.

Comment: Yes apparently that is the reason. grep "pattern" ./*.php is responsive and working. Thanks!

Comment: It works without specified files with the option -r  in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS, with grep version *2.25*.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you don't specify any input file, `grep` waits for you to provide input data on its standard input.

The behavior where `-r` will use the current directory by default is non-standard ([in fact, `-r` itself is](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)), and was introduced in GNU grep 2.11.

Comment: No path, just: (standard input):

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing file name. From the grep's man page the syntax should be as below :

```
grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]

Ex : grep -r pattern your_directory_path
```

Comment: I am using grep (GNU grep) 2.16. It doesn't work for me if I don't specify a file name.